# Images in Sinatra App not found when deployed to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra, assets

This works 100% Locally but when deployed to Heroku, cannot find the image which is in the images folder in the public folder. This is a sinatra app.

I have added this to the config.ru

```
map "/public" do
 run Rack::Directory.new("./public")
end
```

On my index.erb file I have this css:

```
  background: url(images/image1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `map` instead of `set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'` ?

Comment: Did you try `Rack::Directory.new(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/public")`?